# Render loop exploding

Tags: three.js

I made a small demo/boilerplate for loading a custom mesh with Threejs and inspecting it using orbital controls.

The problem here is that when rotating the object the render loop seems to explode and I can't figure out why.

https://codepen.io/rosefalk/pen/ooBYme?editors=0010

```
function render() {
  console.log('render')
  canvasPosition = document.getElementById( "container" ).children;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
}
```

If you look in the console it's chugging away merily at what I assume is ~60 calls a second until you start rotating, then it goes up at extreme rate.

Comment: Are you calling `render` anywhere else, e.g. on the `change` event from `OrbitControls`?

Comment: Found the culprit and close! 

controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

This essentially adds another loop every time controls are updating. I think it's a remnant from when it amde sense to only update when the user was interacting because it's an inspector.

Thanks a lot, let me to the answer.

Comment: This is why many of the examples you see don't use `requestAnimationFrame(render);` for the animation loop, and instead put the looping into an `animate` function which calls `render`. By separating the two concepts, you can still render whenever you need to, even if the animation loop is stopped.

Comment: @Eirinn It appears your scene is static, in which case you do not need to use `requestAnimationFrame` at all. Is your scene static?

Comment: @WestLangley I found the issue and marked it as accepted. Also you're completely right. I also think orbital controls call requestAnimationFrame so I could get away with calling it just once when the async mesh is loaded and then pass the ball to controls. However in time this little pen will evolve so I'll keep it there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - Removal of this part:

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

When controls are updating it calls render, render calls itself and that explodes the whole thing, adding a massive amount of extra calls. It's a remnant from when it made sense to only update the scene on user interaction.